# cumulative frequency given certain conditions in R

Tags: r, multiple-conditions, cumulative-frequency

I am new at R and I do not really know how to count cumulative number of occurrences of a row if it is the same ID but different date.Also, if the first date appears more than once, it should not count in the first attempt.Look at the rows 2 and 3, that is why the column I am trying to build is called "count" and equals to zero. "count" represents the times that the id has appeared but it follows the next two rules:

1.If it is the first appearence of the Id ever, it assigns zero. For example, for Id 1 despite there are two different registers for the very first date of this Id, "count" equals zero.

2.For the next Id 1 appereance (row 3 of Id1 ) it has a different date, that is why "count" equals 2. Because the 01/01/2018 Id1 appeared twice.

This is the DT and the result that I am looking for is in the "count" column:

[image]

Comment: shouldn't the count on second row for id 1 be 1?

Comment: No, because is the same date.But, since the third row for id 1 occured on a different date, it's 2.

Comment: what about 1st row for id 2? why is that 0?

Comment: why the 3rd row for id = 1 is 2 whereas 2nd row for id = 2 is 1? What does `count` represent?

Comment: when Id and date appear the first time it should counts as zero. Then, line 2 for Id2 and the different date (04/05/2018) is one, because there is a previous register for the same id with a different date.

Comment: 1.If it is the first appearence of the Id ever, it assigns zero. For example, for Id 1 despite there are two different registers for the very first date of this Id, "count" equals zero.

2.For the next Id 1 appereance (row 3 of Id1 ) it has a different date, that is why "count" equals 2. Because the 01/01/2018 Id1 appeared twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` to `group_by` `id` and return 0 for the first `date` else return the count of occurrence of 1st `date`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count = ifelse(date == date[1L], 0, sum(date == date[1L])))

#     id   date       count
#   <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
#1     1 01/01/2018     0
#2     1 01/01/2018     0
#3     1 02/01/2018     2
#4     2 03/02/2018     0
#5     2 04/04/2018     1
```

---

Or using base R `ave` with similar logic

```
as.numeric(with(df, ave(date, id, FUN = function(x) 
           ifelse(x == x[1L], 0, sum(x == x[1L])))))
#[1] 0 0 2 0 1
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), date = c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", 
     "02/01/2018", "03/02/2018", "04/04/2018"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one works just fine. The second one, is giving Na's back. With the followin message: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(0, 0, 2)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(0, 1)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @Magggggg that is because your `date` column is factor. Change them to character by doing `df$date <- as.character(df$date)` and then run the second one.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table` where we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'id', create the 'count' as the `sum` of the logical vector (`date == first(date)`), then change the first row of 'count' for each 'id' to 0

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  count := sum(date == first(date)), id]
df[df[, .I[1], id]$V1, count := 0][]
#   id       date count
#1:  1 01/01/2018     0
#2:  1 01/01/2018     2
#3:  1 02/01/2018     2
#4:  2 03/02/2018     0
#5:  2 04/04/2018     1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), date = c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", 
 "02/01/2018", "03/02/2018", "04/04/2018"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```